# Elementary OS reboot error iMac late 2009

Tags: xorg, drivers, graphics, radeon, nomodeset

I need to install Elementary OS on my (late 2009) iMac 11.1.
I am booting from an external USB and in when presented with a GRUB menu, I choose "Install Elementary OS" and then press <kbd>e</kbd> key to edit and add `nomodeset` and then I press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

With Elementary OS installed, I run into problems after rebooting. First I get GRUB to go in normal or recovery mode, I use `nomodeset` again to boot in normal mode but instead of the GUI, I get a command line and it asks me for a username/password. After that, I run `startx` and get a `No screens found` error. I think it has something to do with my graphics card driver (Radeon 4850HD).

Does anyone know how to get back to the GUI mode?